# Flutter/Dart - Instance member 'displayNotification' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, instance

I'm using `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`in a Flutter plugin called `FCMConfig`.

Previously the following code previously worked.

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
    RemoteMessage _notification) async {
  print('Handling a background message: ${_notification.data["title"]}');
  String fcmname = _notification.data["name"];
  String fcmtitle = _notification.data["title"];
  String fcmmessage = _notification.data["message"];
  String title = _notification.data["title_key"];
FCMConfig.displayNotification(title: fcmtitle, body:fcmname);
}
```

But after some updates to the 2.1.2 minimum SDK I've started to get this error;

```
 Instance member 'displayNotification' can't be accessed using static access.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is FCMConfig defined? The error states that you need to create an instance of it.

Comment: It's from the dart package - class FCMConfig extends FCMConfigInterface<AndroidNotificationDetails,
    IOSNotificationDetails, AndroidNotificationSound, StyleInformation> {
  static FCMConfig get instance => FCMConfig();
  @override
  Future<RemoteMessage?> getInitialMessage() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      var intial = await LocaleNotificationManager.getInitialMessage();
      if (intial != null) return intial;
    }
    return await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  }

Comment: Maybe you need to get an instance of it

Comment: Like this? FCMConfig firebaseconfig = FCMConfig.instance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/fcm_config), you are supposed to do this:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
RemoteMessage _notification) async {
   print('Handling a background message: ${_notification.data["title"]}');
   String fcmname = _notification.data["name"];
   String fcmtitle = _notification.data["title"];
   String fcmmessage = _notification.data["message"];
   String title = _notification.data["title_key"];
   FCMConfig().displayNotification(title: fcmtitle, body:fcmname); // <---
}
```

You forgot the parenthesis ().